# kendo ui multiselect remove delete action

Tags: kendo-ui, multi-select

How can i restrict users from deleting the already saved items in the Multi select widget. Users should not be able to delete existing values but can add or remove the new values.

The solution i tried was on databound remove the delete icon like below. It gets deleted but comes back after the call executes the databound method.

Any ideas?

```
onDataBound: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.sender.tagList).find("li span.k-delete").remove();
    }
```

This is the code in the view which calls the above js function on databound

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.Documents)
                      .DataTextField("Description")
                      .DataValueField("Code")
                      .Placeholder("Select Attachment...")
                      .AutoBind(false)
                      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomerDocuments", "CustomerRequest")).ServerFiltering(true))
                      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:400px;"}) 
                      .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))                            
                      )
```

Comment: Show some more code: what is the element you are working with? what's its definition?

Comment: some more code added. I am expecting when the data is bound then js function is called to remove the span elements with class "k.-delete"

Comment: So you want the multi-select to only accept adding of items? You don't want a user to click the little cross and remove the item from the previously selected items?

Comment: @chiapa yes that's correct! When i debug it removes the delete icon but then after function is complete at the end the delete icons come back

Comment: Any ideas or comments?

Comment: Have you tried using the change event to do the same as on the databound event?

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried applying the same method on the change event as on the databound event?

**Razor:**

```
.Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
```

**Javascript:**

```
onChange: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.sender.tagList).find("li span.k-delete").remove();
}
```