# Kendo UI Multiselect: Remove delete action on data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo multiselect UI element and I am trying to check a certain condition and make sure that element is non-deletable right at the initial data load. My code is as follows:

```
$scope.programSelect = $("#selectPrograms1").kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataSource:new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: $scope.programs
                    }),
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    dataValueField:"id",
                    select: addProgram,
                    dataBound: function (e) {
                        //check condition on data
                        //if true then do
                        //$(e.sender.tagList).find("li span.k-delete").remove();
                    },
                    change: programRemove
                }).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

I had some help from [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507752/kendo-ui-multiselect-remove-delete-action). This piece of code doesn't seem to be working for some reason and I'm at a loss. Would appreciate any suggestions. Am I checking at the wrong place?

Comment: seems to work just fine: http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/ogIxU

Comment: @LarsHöppner I think it's an issue when the data source is dynamic. It gets deleted but comes back after the call executes the databound method.

Comment: Try to recreate using one of telerik's demos for angular